# jQuery: Use .attr('href',"") to call javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hyperlink that I am trying to change the href value of with jQuery, to call a function. Previously, this used to point to a url, this was my previous code, where `myUrl` is a string variable being passed in:

```
$('#lnkEdit').attr('href','" + myUrl + "');
```

I need to change this to instead call a function.

I have tried to pass it in as such, where `openDialog` is just my popup function:

```
string editUrl = "javascript:openDialog('myUrl/EditForm.aspx')"
$('#lnkEdit').attr('href','" + editUrl + "');"
```

but that just navigates me to function, as the URL in the browser (the browser tries to navigate to the function call text).

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Why not remove the href and use the click event instead?

Comment: Instead of changing element attributes (as if you were writing HTML) you should bind a click event handler to the element. Look up [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `prop` method, for sample:

```
string editUrl = "javascript:openDialog('myUrl/EditForm.aspx')"

$('#lnkEdit').prop('href', editUrl);
```

But as a good pratice, would be a good approach using a function to provide this window, for sample:

```
$('#lnkEdit').on('click', function() {
   openDialog('myUrl/EditForm.aspx');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical way is to attach a click handler:

```
$('#lnkEdit').on('click', function() {
    openDialog('myUrl/EditForm.aspx');
});
```

Or, if the URL comes from somewhere else during HTML generation:

```
<a id="lnkEdit" href="#" data-href="myUrl/EditForm.aspx">test</a>
```

Then:

```
$('#lnkEdit').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    openDialog($(this).data('href'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change it to something like

    `var editUrl = "openDialog('myUrl/EditForm.aspx')";
    $('#lnkEdit').attr('href',"#");
    $('#lnkEdit').attr('onclick',editUrl);`

This sets the object to change onclick rather than act as a link. It's a slightly nicer way to do it, and simpler I believe.